# Using annoy with Torchtext for nearest neighbor search

Tags: nlp, pytorch, nearest-neighbor, torchtext, annoy

I'm using Torchtext for some NLP tasks, specifically using the built-in embeddings.

I want to be able to do a inverse vector search: Generate a noisy vector, find the vector that is closest to it, then get back the word that is "closest" to the noisy vector.

From the [torchtext docs](https://pytorch.org/text/datasets.html), here's how to attach embeddings to a built-in dataset:

```py
from torchtext.vocab import GloVe
from torchtext import data

embedding = GloVe(name='6B', dim=100)

# Set up fields
TEXT = data.Field(lower=True, include_lengths=True, batch_first=True)
LABEL = data.Field(sequential=False, is_target=True)

# make splits for data
train, test = datasets.IMDB.splits(TEXT, LABEL)

# build the vocabulary
TEXT.build_vocab(train, vectors=embedding, max_size=100000)
LABEL.build_vocab(train)

# Get an example vector
embedding.get_vecs_by_tokens("germany")
```

Then we can build the annoy index:

```
from annoy import AnnoyIndex

num_trees = 50

ann_index = AnnoyIndex(embedding_dims, 'angular')

# Iterate through each vector in the embedding and add it to the index
for vector_num, vector in enumerate(TEXT.vocab.vectors):
    ann_index.add_item(vector_num, vector) # Here's the catch: will vector_num correspond to torchtext.vocab.Vocab.itos?

ann_index.build(num_trees)
```

Then say I want to retrieve a word using a noisy vector:

```
# Get an existing vector
original_vec = embedding.get_vecs_by_tokens("germany")
# Add some noise to it
noise = generate_noise_vector(ndims=100)
noisy_vector = original_vec + noise
# Get the vector closest to the noisy vector
closest_item_idx = ann_index.get_nns_by_vector(noisy_vector, 1)[0]
# Get word from noisy item
noisy_word = TEXT.vocab.itos[closest_item_idx]
```

My question comes in for the last two lines above: The `ann_index` was built using `enumerate` over the `embedding` object, which is a Torch tensor.

The `[vocab][2]` object has its own `itos` list that given an index returns a word.

My question is this: Can I be certain that the order in which words appear in the itos list, is the same as the order in `TEXT.vocab.vectors`? How can I map one index to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I be certain that the order in which words appear in the `itos` list, is the same as the order in `TEXT.vocab.vectors`?

Yes.

The `Field` class will always instantiate a `Vocab` object ([source](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/43acc7534738ca6af91c19524667738d4b3f1fa3/torchtext/data/field.py#L309)), and since you are passing the pre-trained vectors to `TEXT.build_vocab`, the `Vocab` constructor will [call](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/43acc7534738ca6af91c19524667738d4b3f1fa3/torchtext/vocab.py#L100) the `load_vectors` function.

```py
if vectors is not None:
    self.load_vectors(vectors, unk_init=unk_init, cache=vectors_cache)
```

In the `load_vectors`, the `vectors` are [filled](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/43acc7534738ca6af91c19524667738d4b3f1fa3/torchtext/vocab.py#L194) by enumerating the words in the `itos`.

```py
for i, token in enumerate(self.itos):
    start_dim = 0
    for v in vectors:
        end_dim = start_dim + v.dim
        self.vectors[i][start_dim:end_dim] = v[token.strip()]
        start_dim = end_dim
    assert(start_dim == tot_dim)
```

Therefore, you can be certain that `itos` and `vectors` will have the same order.

Comment: Thanks for linking the code. I did a bit of reviewing myself and it seems like it is indeed the case. I'll accept this as correct. Still feels icky to me though, there should be a function to get the vectors back from the TEXT.vocab object.